# Javascript in Virtual Directory unaware of Virtual Directory

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, virtual-directory

Say I have the site 
    http://localhost/virtual 
where virtual is the virtual directory

I have an Ajax request that is defined in a javascript file using JQuery

```
$.getJSON("/Controller/Action")
```

When this is called, the client tries to find the url at the root level i.e.
    http://localhost/Controller/Action

If I add the tilde (~) symbol in, it turns into 
    http://localhost/virtual/~/Controller/Action

It should (if it was to do what I wanted) resolve to 
    http://localhost/virtual/Controller/Action

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a way, so I have just put a relative path e.g. ../Controller/Action

Comment: It helps if you tell us the expected output. You're only telling us two outputs that you DONT want. What DO you want?

Comment: I want it to be output as http://localhost/virtual/Controller/Action

Comment: try: $.getJSON("./Controller/Action")

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Aku's hint above looked right but it didn't want to work for me. Finally I figured out to use it like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var config = {
        contextPath: '<%= @Url.Content("~")  %>'
    };
</script>
```

and then in my JavaScript I use it like this

config.contextPath + 'myAppPath".

So in case of no virtual directory this resolves to
"/" + "myAppPath"
and in case of a virtual directory this resolves to
"/VirtualPath/" +  + "myAppPath"

and this finally worked for me.

Comment: Works beautifully for me!  And simple :)

Comment: works fine with me too, but I needed to remove the tags <%= %> to make it works

Answer (score 15):

I used this solution successfully

Place the following element in your masterpage

```
<%= Html.Hidden("HiddenCurrentUrl", Url.Action("Dummy"))%>
```

Declare a global variable in your main javascript file

```
var baseUrl = "";
```

Set baseUrl to the value of "HiddenCurrentUrl" when your javascript is loaded

```
baseUrl = $("#HiddenCurrentUrl").val();
baseUrl = baseUrl.substring(0, baseUrl.indexOf("Dummy"));
```

Use baseUrl

```
$.getJSON(baseUrl + "Action")
```

**EDIT Improved solution**

In your controller

```
ViewBag.BaseUrl = Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) + Request.ApplicationPath + "/";
```

In your master page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var YourNameSpace = YourNameSpace || {};
    YourNameSpace.config = {
        baseUrl: "@ViewBag.BaseUrl"
    }
</script>
```

Use your baseUrl

```
$.getJSON(YourNameSpace.config.baseUrl + "Action")
```

Comment: I am marking this as the answer as it is funky, and I like funky mixes of jQuery and MVC. Although I might use something diff to using Url.Action as the substring thing isn't so clean

Comment: Great that you found this helpful! I'm not satisfied with the Url.Action solution so please tell me how you end up solving it. I hate URL stuff. Always problems between dev/test/prod environments.

Comment: I voted up as well. It is funky, but I am unable to think of a more elegant solution right now and this works... clever.

Comment: This is a poor approach to solutions that wrap up their logic in multiple JS files and are creating closures around the logic to ensure things are done appropriately.

Comment: @offthat Edited the solution to use namespacing. Is that a better approach?

Answer (score 4):

Another way to get a base url is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.g_baseUrl = '@Url.Content("~")';
</script>
```

For example, if you run your app from **SomeName** virtual directory then
**window.g_baseUrl** variable will be equal to **/SomeName/**

Benefit of this method is an ability to call actions in the other controllers like so

```
$.getJSON(window.g_baseUrl + "AnotherController/Action")
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe,`$.getJSON("Controller/Action")` will do?

Comment: No, it just adds to the Path. It might work if the js file was in the root.

Answer (score 2):

The tilde shortcut for your application root path is a special feature of ASP.NET, not part of URLs themselves. Consequently trying to use a URL with a tilde in from JavaScript won't resolve the site root, it'll just give you a literal `~` as you can see.

You'd need to pass the value of the application root path to JavaScript so it can construct URLs itself. I'm not that familiar with ASP.NET but I believe you could do something like:

```
<script type="text/javscript">
    var approot= <%= JavaScriptSerializer.Serialize(Request.ApplicationPath) %>;
    ... $.getJSON(approot+'/Controller/Action') ...;
</script>
```

A simpler way to do it if you know there's a link on the page to the approot would be to read the `href` of that link:

```
var approot= $('#homepagelink').attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative Path to the JS file was the only solution I found
    $.getJSON("../Controller/Action")

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is very old but I was lately struggling with this issue and was able to resolve it using

```
  url:'<%=VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Include/cntrols/Data.aspx") %>',
```

this works great in my ajax call...

Answer (score 0):

It is too late to answer this question. But may be useful to someone as I had same problem. Instead of doing all this steps mentioned in above answers, better way is to use

`Url.Action('action','controller')`.

It'll generate url `/VIRDIR/controller/action` if it is running from virtual directory or generate `/controller/action` in other case.