# AJAX getJSON call works on IIS express but not on IIS (ASP.NET/MVC4)

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, rest

It finds the MVC controller just find with IIS express. But once I switch to IIS and this call is made it cannot find the resource (404)

Is '/api/Values/5' correct? OR must it be done differently to work in IIS and IIS express ?

If I run in IIS and I type in to the URL

```
http://localhost/AGS.Web/api/values/5
```

It finds it with no problem

```
var RefreshInstructions = function () {
    var SelectedTaskValue = $("#SelectedTaskType_Id").val();
    // Send an AJAX request
    $.getJSON("/api/Values/5", function (data) {
        $('#divTaskInstructions').html(data);
    });
}

Key Value
Request GET /api/Values/5 HTTP/1.1
```

EDIT 1: it is not reffered to as AGS.Web when I use IIS EXPRESS so I am hoping there is a generic way to refer to the URL for both cases?

EDIT 2: Navigating to `http://localhost/AGS.Web/api/values/5` works find but I guess the problem is 'AGS.Web' does not existing in then AJAX call.. So should I prepend some sort of server variable something like HttpContext.Current.Request.Url; ?

Comment: `/AGS.Web/api/values/5 !== /api/Values/5`

Comment: What happens if you navigate there with the browser directly?

Answer (score 4):

If you deploy your application to IIS your URI must include your application name as well. So, as your application name is `AGS.Web`, then your URI must be `http://localhost/AGS.Web/api/valuues/5`.

You can automatically detect your baseUri and have it prepend by adding a line in your master page or shared `_Layout.cshtml`:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var config = {
            contextPath: '@Url.Content("~")'
        }
    </script>
```

Then in your JS you prepend by:

```
var baseUri = config.contextPath;

$.getJSON(baseUri + "api/values/5", function (data) {
    $('#divTaskInstructions').html(data);
});
```

I got this from a discussion [javascript-in-virtual-directory-unaware-of-virtual-directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116788/javascript-in-virtual-directory-unaware-of-virtual-directory) that I ran across while I was having the same issue during a deployment this week.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between IIS Express and IIS from this point of view.
Default IIS configuration responds to the GET verb, so you've probably configured your web application to be activated on a different URL or even limited to certain hostnames.