# jquery GET to location in virtual directory AND behind a load balancer (mvc web api)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have the same problem described here:
[Javascript in Virtual Directory unaware of Virtual Directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116788/javascript-in-virtual-directory-unaware-of-virtual-directory)

But the proposed solutions of using a hidden field or a server-side generated json settings object don't work for me, since the server-side doesn't actually know it's own url. If I do Url.Content("~") I just get an ip of one of the machines the code runs on so I can never use that path in javascript. It also returns a http url instead of the outside https url.

So to be more precise:
https://myhost.com/myapp/ /* here's where my code runs */

I could use relative paths in jquery (like this: $.get('api/controller')) but the application does not work if the user uses 'https://myhost.com/myapp' (so no trailing slash). (well actually the page gets loaded but the call-backs fail because of the lack of trailing slash)

I could use absolute urls but the server-side code does not know the actual url...

Is there any way to have javascript return the full absolute path WITH virtual directory WITH trailing slash (even though there is no trailing slash in the browser address)?

Thx

Answer (score 3):

Ok, got it. It's now a combo of two earlier answers given in other related questions:

I keep using relative paths and I also use the settings json, which will hold the relative path containing the virtual directory:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var settings = {
        baseUrl: '@Url.Content("~")'
    };
</script>
```

This will resolve into this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var settings = {
        baseUrl: '/MyApp/' /* <-- always has trailing slash */
    };
</script>
```

And I just have to prefix that to every jQuery $.get operation I do.

If anyone has something better, I'm very open to suggestions!